# How to pass char pointer to C++ API from python?

Tags: python, c++, nullpointerexception, ctypes, tesseract

I am trying to call the following C++ method from my python code:

```
TESS_API TessResultRenderer* TESS_CALL TessTextRendererCreate(const char* outputbase)
{
    return new TessTextRenderer(outputbase);
}
```

I'm having difficulty with how to pass the pointer to the method:

Is following the right way?

```
textRenderer = self.tesseract.TessTextRendererCreate(ctypes.c_char)
```

or should I be doing:

```
outputbase = ctypes.c_char * 512
textRenderer = self.tesseract.TessTextRendererCreate(ctypes.pointer(outputbase))
```

Doing above gives me error:

```
TypeError: _type_ must have storage info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing in a string.

For example:

```
self.tesseract.TessTextRendererCreate('/path/to/output/file/without/extension')
```

Here's a generalized example with a mock API. In `lib.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  const char * foo (const char * input) {
    std::cout <<
      "The function 'foo' was called with the following "
      "input argument: '" << input << "'" << std::endl;

    return input;
  }
}
```

Compile the shared library using:

```
clang++ -fPIC -shared lib.cc -o lib.so
```

Then, in Python:

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
>>> lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
>>> lib.foo.restype = c_char_p
>>> result = lib.foo('Hello world!')
The function 'foo' was called with the following input argument: 'Hello world!'
>>> result
'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Passing in a string worked for me! however, the calls to different methods is failing. I asked a related question and was wondering if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871072/segmentation-fault-while-calling-cpp-function-from-python

Comment: Note that a string should only be directly passed for `const char *`. If it's not `const`, use `ctypes.create_string_buffer('initial value, or use an integer size')`. Python strings are semantically immutable, and CPython depends on this to allow interning various strings in code objects and attribute names. If an interned string gets mutated, it's not just a matter of data corruption but also breaks attribute access and dict lookup if the string is a dict key.